# How to clear input type image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a camera feature and the captured image will be displayed in this tag. I want to clear that image if I hit on reset button. I tried .empty() .clear() .reset. None of them works. How can I clear input type image?

```
<input type="image" id="myimage"/>

function resetimage(){
$('#myimage').empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing like `clear()` . What you can do is `hide()` it. And whenever you want to show it back `show()` it.

Alternatively you can try removing src attribute and setting src attr to `""`, but some browsers show the broken image which doen't look good.

Comment: ok, thank you. I think I can set the image.src to null or something to make it disappear.